# Css Flex styling in the same row

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, flexbox

Hey I am writing a project and I am trying to put all of the items in the same row
I tried using the flexbox but the items appear over each other and I don't know how to fix it
I have made a code sandbox with my problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-bush-kzdsvl

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, but it's your hierarchy with the divs that's out of line. I made some edits here: https://codesandbox.io/s/7mmdy7

If you want the slider on the same line too, remove lines 60 and 61.